# get selected element id from d3.drag function call

Tags: javascript, d3.js

When dragging, in the `dragged` function call, two parameters are given:  `event` and `d`

How can I get the selected element index?

In the code below the `dragged` function is not working since the index of dragged element not correct!

```js
drag_nodes()

function drag_nodes() {
        var data = {
                nodes: [{
                        name: "A",
                        x: 200,
                        y: 150
                }, {
                        name: "B",
                        x: 140,
                        y: 300
                }, {
                        name: "C",
                        x: 300,
                        y: 300
                }, {
                        name: "D",
                        x: 300,
                        y: 180
                }],
                links: [{
                        source: 0,
                        target: 1
                }, {
                        source: 1,
                        target: 2
                }, {
                        source: 2,
                        target: 3
                }, ]
        };

        var c10 = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
        var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", 1200)
                .attr("height", 800);

        var drag = d3.drag()
                .on("start", dragstarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragended);

        function dragstarted(event, d) {
                d3.select(this).raise().attr("stroke", "black");
        }

        function dragged(event, d) {
                d.x += event.dx
                d.y += event.dy
                d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x).attr("cy", d.y);
                links.each(function(e, i) {
                        var idx = 0 // select element idx
                        if (e.source == idx) {
                                d3.select(this).attr("x1", d.x).attr("y1", d.y);
                        }else if (e.target == idx) {
                                d3.select(this).attr("x2", d.x).attr("y2", d.y);
                        }
                });
        }

        function dragended(event, d) {
                d3.select(this).attr("stroke", null);
        }
    
        var links = svg.selectAll("link")
                .data(data.links)
                .enter()
                .append("line")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .attr("x1", function(l) {
                        var sourceNode = data.nodes.filter(function(d, i) {
                                return i == l.source
                        })[0];
                        d3.select(this).attr("y1", sourceNode.y);
                        return sourceNode.x
                })
                .attr("x2", function(l) {
                        var targetNode = data.nodes.filter(function(d, i) {
                                return i == l.target
                        })[0];
                        d3.select(this).attr("y2", targetNode.y);
                        return targetNode.x
                })
                .attr("fill", "none")
                .attr("stroke", "black");

        var nodes = svg.selectAll("node")
                .data(data.nodes)
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("cx", function(d) {
                        return d.x
                })
                .attr("cy", function(d) {
                        return d.y
                })
                .attr("r", 15)
                .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
                        return c10(i);
                })
                .call(drag);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index is not part of either the `event` or `d` arguments.

Two options can be considered:

Update your `data.nodes` objects to include an `idx` property with:

```
data.nodes.forEach((n, i) => n.idx = i);
```

And then in the `.each` loop you can simply have:

```
var idx = d.idx;
```

Or, if you need to get the index (`idx`) dynamically, in the `.each` loop use:

```
var idx = data.nodes.findIndex(l => l.name === d.name);
```

Option 1 is below:

```js
drag_nodes()

function drag_nodes() {
        var data = {
                nodes: [{
                        name: "A",
                        x: 200,
                        y: 150
                }, {
                        name: "B",
                        x: 140,
                        y: 300
                }, {
                        name: "C",
                        x: 300,
                        y: 300
                }, {
                        name: "D",
                        x: 300,
                        y: 180
                }],
                links: [{
                        source: 0,
                        target: 1
                }, {
                        source: 1,
                        target: 2
                }, {
                        source: 2,
                        target: 3
                }, ]
        };
        
        // option 1
        data.nodes.forEach((n, i) => n.idx = i);

        var c10 = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
        var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", 1200)
                .attr("height", 800);

        var drag = d3.drag()
                .on("start", dragstarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragended);

        function dragstarted(event, d) {
                d3.select(this).raise().attr("stroke", "black");
        }

        function dragged(event, d) {
                d.x += event.dx
                d.y += event.dy
                d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x).attr("cy", d.y);
                links.each(function(e, i) {
                        var idx = d.idx; // option 1
                        // var idx = data.nodes.findIndex(l => l.name === d.name); // option 2

                        if (e.source == idx) {
                                d3.select(this).attr("x1", d.x).attr("y1", d.y);
                        }else if (e.target == idx) {
                                d3.select(this).attr("x2", d.x).attr("y2", d.y);
                        }
                });
        }

        function dragended(event, d) {
                d3.select(this).attr("stroke", null);
        }
    
        var links = svg.selectAll("link")
                .data(data.links)
                .enter()
                .append("line")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .attr("x1", function(l) {
                        var sourceNode = data.nodes.filter(function(d, i) {
                                return i == l.source
                        })[0];
                        d3.select(this).attr("y1", sourceNode.y);
                        return sourceNode.x
                })
                .attr("x2", function(l) {
                        var targetNode = data.nodes.filter(function(d, i) {
                                return i == l.target
                        })[0];
                        d3.select(this).attr("y2", targetNode.y);
                        return targetNode.x
                })
                .attr("fill", "none")
                .attr("stroke", "black");

        var nodes = svg.selectAll("node")
                .data(data.nodes)
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("cx", function(d) {
                        return d.x
                })
                .attr("cy", function(d) {
                        return d.y
                })
                .attr("r", 15)
                .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
                        return c10(i);
                })
                .call(drag);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
```